# shell script to format text, merge lines, add tabs

Tags: bash, shell

```
20140918-17:31:19.835
34=11
52=20140918-17:31:19.812
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
20140918-17:31:19.837
34=12
52=20140918-17:31:19.813
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
20140918-17:31:19.838
34=13
52=20140918-17:31:19.813
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
273=17:31:19.797
```

I have this input and want to format it like this:

```
34=11 20140918-17:31:19.835
    52=20140918-17:31:19.812
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
34=12 20140918-17:31:19.837
    52=20140918-17:31:19.813
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
34=13 20140918-17:31:19.838
    52=20140918-17:31:19.813
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
```

I have no shell scripting experience, I'm afraid this question might be inappropriate but if you could point me to a good shell scripting tutorial that would get me started I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `awk`:

```
awk '!/=/{m=$0; next}m{$0=$0 FS m; m=0}/^52=/{$0="\t"$0}/^273=/{$0="\t\t"$0}1' file
```

### How it works:

- `!/=/{m=$0; next}` - If the line doesn't contain `=`, the line record (`$0`) is assigned to the `m` variable.  `next` skips to the next line as no further processing is needed.
- `m{$0=$0 FS m; m=0}` - If `m` is defined (greater than zero), append the current line (`$0`) with the field separator (`FS`) and the variable `m` (previous line).  Finally, reset the `m` variable to zero as we need to make sure this code block keeps getting executed immediately after the line that does not contain an `=` character.
- `/^52=/{$0="\t"$0}` - If the current line starts with `52=`, prefix the current line record (`$0`) with a tab character (`\t`)
- `/^273=/{$0="\t\t"$0}` - If the current line starts with `273=`, prefix the current line record with two tab characters.
- `1` - This is just a little shorthand trick for saying `{print}` regardless of any condition.  The `1` is just telling `awk` print is true.  You could really substitute this with anything truthy since `awk`'s default action is to print if a condition is true and no following code block is provided.

On any UNIX system, `awk` is the go to language for manipulating text files.

I've found [this intro](http://ferd.ca/awk-in-20-minutes.html) to be exceptionally concise.  Also, [awk.info](http://awk.info) has a wide collection of overviews and tutorials.  As far as documentation goes, the [GNU Awk User's Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: As you are answering a question posted by someone with "no shell scripting experience", it would greatly increase the quality of your answer if you provided some explanation of how it works.

Comment: Agreed, I'm getting to that.

Comment: Thanks and I'd really appreciate any explanation you can provide as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using `sed`

```
sed -r '
    /^2014/ {                          # For lines starting with 2014
        N;                             # Append next line to pattern space
        s/^([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)/\2 \1/;  # Merge the first line with second
    }
    /^52/ {                            # For lines starting with 52
        s/^/\t/                        # Add a tab in the front of the line
    }
    /^273/ {                           # For lines starting with 273
        s/^/\t\t/                      # Add a tab in the front of the line
    }' file
34=11 20140918-17:31:19.835
    52=20140918-17:31:19.812
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
34=12 20140918-17:31:19.837
    52=20140918-17:31:19.813
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
34=13 20140918-17:31:19.838
    52=20140918-17:31:19.813
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
        273=17:31:19.797
```

As a one-liner:

```
sed -r '/^2014/N;s/^([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)/\2 \1/;/^52/s/^/\t/;/^273/s/^/\t\t/' file
```

Comment: only thing is the spaces are not maintained as you used \t and seems like he wanted 4 spaces for 2nd line n 8 for leaf level lines.

Comment: @ArunSangal I had that in place first then edited out after reading the question title. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

AWK is great as Jaypal, John described with the solution. As you are new, you can do the same by running basic Unix/Linux level commands and it'll help you understand what those commands are doing by seeing their man pages.

Note the following solution is a not the efficient solution like John/JayPal provided but will get you exactly what I meant above and with your output request.

Assuming your file name is 1.txt" which contains the data, then run the following **runme.sh**

```
 #!/bin/bash
 grep "^[0-9][0-9]=[0-9][0-9]$" 1.txt > 2-2.txt
 grep "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.*-[0-9][0-9]*\:[0-9][0-9]*.*\.[0-9][0-9]*$" 1.txt > datetime.txt
 grep "^[0-9][0-9]=.*-[0-9][0-9]*\:[0-9][0-9]*.*\.[0-9][0-9]*$" 1.txt > equal_datetime.txt
 grep "^[0-9][0-9][0-9]=.*[0-9]$" 1.txt > 3_eq_lines.txt

 paste 2-2.txt datetime.txt equal_datetime.txt  > headers.txt
 c=1; while read line1 line2 line3; do echo -e "$line1 $line2\n    $line3"; echo -e "`tail -n +$c 3_eq_lines.txt | head -4|sed "s/^/        /"`"; ((c+=3)); done < headers.txt
 rm 2-2.txt datetime.txt equal_datetime.txt 3_eq_lines.txt headers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  perl

```
perl -lnE '$l1=$_,next unless m/=/;        #store the line without =
           s/$/ $l1/ if m/^\d\d=\d\d$/;    #merge this line with the stored
           s/^/\t/ if m/^\d+=\d{8}/;       #if the = is followed by 8 digits -> 1xtab
           s/^/\t\t/ if m/^\d+=\d\d:/;     #if the = is followed by 2digits and : -> 2xtab
           print $_;' filename
```